# Get key and Iv and type of encryption from EVP_CIPHER_CTX or EVP_CIPHER?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography

I'm trying to get iv and key and other things like name of crypto system like from `EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx` or `EVP_CIPHER *kt` in OpenSSL. I searched a lot but no function found that returns key and iv.

Answer (score 1):

The `EVP_CIPHER` object represents the abstract implementation of a particular cipher. It remains unchanged no matter how many times you use it and does not store the IV or key.

The `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` stores data specific to a particular encryption or decryption.
The original IV that you set in the `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` can be obtained using the function EVP_CIPHER_CTX_original_iv():

```
const unsigned char *EVP_CIPHER_CTX_original_iv(const EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx);
```

It is not currently possible to get the key back.